# add a row of dummy text to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, arcgis

for reasons that have to do with checking an error in ArcGis, where my data is going, I need to add a row at the top that contains dummy variables, which I would like to be Column1:Column(n)

For example, I have this:

```
  ID A  B    C
1  A 1  8 set1
2  A 2  9 set2
3  B 3 10 set1
4  B 4 11 set2
5  B 5 12 set3
6  C 6 13 set1
7  C 7 14 set2
```

I would like this:

```
       ID       A       B       C
1 Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
2       A       1       8    set1
3       A       2       9    set2
4       B       3      10    set1
5       B       4      11    set2
6       B       5      12    set3
7       C       6      13    set1
8       C       7      14    set2
```

I understand that this would make some numeric columns into character. Some dummy data from dput is below. As a note, my real data set has many more actual columns.

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C"), A = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), B = c(8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14), C = c("set1", 
"set2", "set1", "set2", "set3", "set1", "set2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyverse`, use `add_row` after converting the columns to `character`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
 mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>% 
 add_row(!!! setNames(str_c("Column", seq_along(.)), names(df)), .before = 1)
```

-output

```
    ID       A       B       C
1 Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
2       A       1       8    set1
3       A       2       9    set2
4       B       3      10    set1
5       B       4      11    set2
6       B       5      12    set3
7       C       6      13    set1
8       C       7      14    set2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option

```
> rbind(as.list(paste0("Column", seq_along(df))), df)
       ID       A       B       C
1 Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
2       A       1       8    set1
3       A       2       9    set2
4       B       3      10    set1
5       B       4      11    set2
6       B       5      12    set3
7       C       6      13    set1
8       C       7      14    set2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R solution:

```
df[nrow(df)+1,1:4] <- paste0(rep("Column", 4), 1:4)
df <- df[c(8,1:7),]
rownames(df) <- NULL
```

```
       ID       A       B       C
1 Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
2       A       1       8    set1
3       A       2       9    set2
4       B       3      10    set1
5       B       4      11    set2
6       B       5      12    set3
7       C       6      13    set1
8       C       7      14    set2
```

As an alternative we could use `InsertRow` function from `DataCombine` package:

```
#install.packages("DataCombine")
library(DataCombine)

InsertRow(df, NewRow = paste0(rep("Column", 4), 1:4), RowNum = 1)
```

```
       ID       A       B       C
1 Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
2       A       1       8    set1
3       A       2       9    set2
4       B       3      10    set1
5       B       4      11    set2
6       B       5      12    set3
7       C       6      13    set1
8       C       7      14    set2
```